# conditions work separately but not together in filtering dataframe rows [ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

Again I am trying to single out certain rows under the time condition to compute the mean/std of separate time periods.

```
file = pd.read_csv('test/Res/1002', sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-8')

print(file['hm']==47)
print(file['hm']==48)
print(1<=file['hm']<=14)
```

I get the correctly evaluated True/False list of booleans. But in the following, instead receive this -> `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

```
overn_std = file[(file['hm'] == 47)| (file['hm'] == 48) | (1 <= file['hm'] <= 14) ]
```

[image]

In the past I resolved the same issue by replacing condition `or` with |.
dtype of column hm is int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need split `(1 <= file['hm'] <= 14)` to 2 separate conditions chained by `&` for `AND`:

```
overn_std = file[(file['hm'] == 47) | 
                 (file['hm'] == 48) | 
                 ((file['hm'] >= 1) & (file['hm'] <= 14)) ]
```

You can also create each mask separately:

```
m1 = (file['hm'] == 47)
m2 = (file['hm'] == 48)
m3 = (file['hm'] >= 1)
m4 = (file['hm'] <= 14)

overn_std = file[m1 | m2 | (m3 & m4 )]
```

Better is use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
overn_std = file[(file['hm'].isin([47,48])) | (file['hm'].between(1,14)) ]
```

**Sample**:

```
file = pd.DataFrame({
    'hm': range(50)
})


overn_std = file[(file['hm'].isin([47,48])) | (file['hm'].between(1,14)) ]
print (overn_std)
    hm
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
47  47
48  48
```

Comment: thx. to note, what's interesting (and not completely understood) is that it works if I save the condition statement in separate variable (for instance cond1, cond2) then merge as cond1 & cond2 inside the indexing of file[].

Comment: @HSL - Yes, this aprach is very readable if many compliacted conditions. But it is same, only working with variables e.g. `m1`, `m2` instead  `(file['hm'] == 47)`, `(file['hm'] == 48)`.